# Get Sub total, total and grand total report in php from mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, report

I need to find out :

1) How many total entries have done by a particular user on a date 
2) How many total entries have been done on a particular date.

I am able to run this query :

```
SELECT app_user,DATE(app_doe),COUNT(*) AS entries,`institution`,`qualification` FROM `details` WHERE MONTH(app_doe)="12" AND YEAR(app_doe)="2017" GROUP BY app_user,DATE(app_doe),`institution`,`qualification` ORDER BY DATE(app_doe) DESC,app_user
```

and get the following output from the mysql table.

[image]

I need to arrange data in a report based on the above mysql query output like this using php , but i am not getting any idea how to count total,subtotals as mentioned above :

[image]

Please provide pointers on how to go ahead ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by changing `GROUP BY whatever` to `GROUP BY whatever WITH ROLLUP` in your query.  You'll get extra rows at the end of every grouping with rolled up values, and NULL values indicating the groups over which each rolled up value was determined. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html

You may need to adjust your rendering program to do a good job presenting the modified query.

Comment: thanks.. yeah WITH ROLLUP works... but i cant apply ORDER BY column when i use Group By WITH ROLLUP... I am getting this error : Error Code: 1221
Incorrect usage of CUBE/ROLLUP and ORDER BY

Comment: Put the ordering you require in your `GROUP BY` command and it should work.  Or wrap the whole query in an outer query and order that. This issue is mentioned in the document to which I linked.